# New Mongoose object contains old data during Mocha test

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mocha.js

I am trying to write mocha tests for custom methods a mongoose model.  When I run my tests they are failing because when I create a new model it fails.

Here is my code:

game.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var gameSchema = new Schema({

userName: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
currentScore: {type: Number, default: 0},
currentFrame: {type: Number, default: 0},
frames: {
    type: Array, default: [
        {
            bowls: [null, null],
            score: null
        },
        {
            bowls: [null, null],
            score: null
        },
        {
            bowls: [null, null],
            score: null
        },
        {
            bowls: [null, null],
            score: null
        },
        {
            bowls: [null, null],
            score: null
        },
        {
            bowls: [null, null],
            score: null
        },
        {
            bowls: [null, null],
            score: null
        },
        {
            bowls: [null, null],
            score: null
        },
        {
            bowls: [null, null],
            score: null
        },
        {
            bowls: [null, null, null],
            score: null
        }
    ]
}
});

gameSchema.methods.addBowl = function (count) {
//Ensure the count is an int so that "3" + "7" != 37
count = parseInt(count);

var frame = this.getCurrentFrame();
var index = this._doc.currentFrame;

//Empty frame add the pin count
if (this.isFrameEmpty(index)) {
    if (count > 10) {
        throw "Cannot bowl more than 10 pins";
    }
    frame.bowls[0] = count;
}

//First ball bowled and it was not a strike
else if (!this.isFrameEmpty(index) && !this.strike(index) && frame.bowls[1] == null) {


    if (parseInt(frame.bowls[0]) + count > 10) {
        throw "Cannot bowl more than 10 pins in a frame"
    }
    frame.bowls[1] = count;
    this.nextFrame();
}

//Previous ball was a strike and not in the last frame
else if (this.strike(index) && index < 9) {
    index = this.nextFrame();
    this.getBowlsInFrame(index)[0] = count;
}
//Spare in the last frame
else if (this.spare(index) && index == 9) {
    frame.bowls[2] = count;
}
//Previous ball was a strike and in last frame
else if (this.strike(index) && index == 9 && frame.bowls[1] == null) {
    frame.bowls[1] = count;
}
else if (this.strike(index) && index == 9 && frame.bowls[1] != null) {
    frame.bowls[2] = count;
} else {
    throw "gameSchema over!";
}
```

};
    }

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Game', gameSchema);
```

test/game.js

```
var Game = require('../game');
var expect = require('chai').expect;


describe("Game", function () {

describe("#getFrame", function () {
    it("Return the frame with the given index", function () {
        var game = new Game();
        var indexes = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

        indexes.forEach(function (value) {
            var frame = game.getFrame(0);
            expect(frame).to.have.a.property('bowls');
            expect(frame).to.have.a.property('score');
        });

        expect(function () {
            game.getFrame(10)
        }).to.throw('Indexing past 10th frame');
    })
});

describe('#addBowl', function () {
    it("After a strike add the next bowl to the next frame", function () {
        var game = new Game();
        game.addBowl(10);
        game.addBowl(5);

        expect(game.currentFrame).to.equal(1);
    });

});

describe('#addBowl', function() {
    it("Not allow more than 10 pins in a frame", function () {
        var game = new Game();
        console.log(JSON.stringify(game));
        expect(function () {
            game.addBowl(11)
        }).to.throw("Cannot bowl more than 10 pins");

        expect(function () {
            game.addBowl(7);
            game.addBowl(4);
        }).to.throw("Cannot bowl more than 10 pins");

        game = {};
    });

   });
});
```

Where I console log the new game in the last test the game already has data from the previous tests.

How do I create a new object that does not have any data for the last test?

Comment: How are your custom methods implemented? Are they async? If so, are you stubbing them somehow?

Comment: I edited the original post to show the custom method that is breaking.

Comment: It sounds to me like you might be assigning properties to the model class instead of the document, but it's hard to say without the rest of the methods (and perhaps the full schema).

Comment: The addBowl method is the only one giving me an issue.  I updated again to show the full schema.  How would I ensure the methods update the document instead of the model?  I thought that was the difference between gameSchema.static and gameSchema.method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a stripped down version of your code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

var gameSchema = new Schema({
  frames: {
    type: Array,
    default: [{
      bowls: [null, null],
      score: null
    }]
  }
});

gameSchema.methods.addBowl = function(count) {
  this.frames[0].bowls[0] = 123;
};

var Game = mongoose.model('Game', gameSchema);

var game1 = new Game();
game1.addBowl();
console.log('%j', game1);

var game2 = new Game();
console.log('%j', game2);
```

As you can see, `game2` will have the same value in `frames[0].bowls[0]` as `game1`. That's because of your default declaration, which gets shared across all instances. In other words: you only have one `[null, null]` array for `bowls` that gets shared between documents (and is also used for new documents, as you are seeing in your code as well).

I believe that setting defaults for arrays in Mongoose is problematic anyway, so I would suggest rewriting your schema to something like this:

```
var bowlSchema = new Schema({
  bowls : [ Number ],
  score : Number,
});

var gameSchema = new Schema({
  frames: [ bowlSchema ] 
});
```

With validation, or from within your instance methods, you can assure that the various arrays maintain their correct sizes.